# How to deal with very little data

Tags: machine-learning, small-sample

I thought I understood the train/validation split basics but this question got me confused. I could acquire very little data. I don't have it already, which is why I cannot just experiment with it. I could either do LOOCV on it, but I believe it is too little data to do any sort of training on it (76 data points, and I want to have 4 or 5 parameters that I pick out of many more since I already tried with fewer on a similar problem and it was clearly not enough). The goal is to get a good correlation between my outputs and the data on those 76 points. What I would do is just guess or grid search the parameters until I get a good enough correlation, and treat my entire data as validation. Is this in any way better than LOOCV? Which approach is more worth my time? I am only looking for positive correlations on normalized data, and I will use expert information to figure out which parameters are likely to have most impact. Thanks

Comment: If you grid search the parameters using your data, then you *are* training on it

Comment: @J.Delaney thanks a lot! Everything makes sense now

Comment: When you have little data you need either a less complex model or more a priori constraints. And as @J.Delaney said, if you gridsearch you are training, if you use the whole dataset for training there can be no validation. So you need to train on a subset and test with the rest.